# Hide div with javascript when no link

Tags: javascript, jquery, hide

I have a website into modx cms, I'm trying to remove or hide a div when into that div there is no  tag.
How can I do this?

I tried this but no luck:

```
jQuery(function($) {
if ($(".pages a")) {$(".pages").remove();}
});

< div class="pages">[+previous+] [+pages+] [+next+]< /div>
```

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Are you trying to remove the next/previous link if there is no next page?

Comment: Tags means,  I could't get your

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to check if the `<a>` tag exists inside the div then you could try:

```
if($(".pages a").length == 0) {
    // links don't exist
    $(".pages").remove();
} else {
    // links exist
}
```

Comment: Thanks all for the answers! the first one did it for me.

Answer (score 1):

another shorter answer would be

```
$('.pages:not(:has(>a))').css("display", "none");
```

[click to see...](http://jsfiddle.net/crtEs/)

[reference jQuery.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you want:

```
$(function($) {
    $(".pages").each(function(){
        if(!$(this).find('a').length)
            $(this).remove();
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Hide it this way, so that you can show them up when there are links:

```
if ($(".pages a").length == 0) {
    $(".pages").hide();
}
```

And when the links are there, or you making an AJAX call, do this:

```
$(".pages").show();
```